# apply a rolling mean to a database by an index

Tags: r, statistics, zoo

I would like to calculate a rolling mean on data in a single data frame by multiple ids. See my example dataset below.

```
date <- as.Date(c("2015-02-01", "2015-02-02", "2015-02-03", "2015-02-04", 
          "2015-02-05", "2015-02-06", "2015-02-07", "2015-02-08",  
          "2015-02-09", "2015-02-10", "2015-02-01", "2015-02-02", 
          "2015-02-03", "2015-02-04", "2015-02-05", "2015-02-06", 
          "2015-02-07", "2015-02-08", "2015-02-09", "2015-02-10"))
index <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a",
           "b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b")
x <- runif(20,1,100)
y <- runif(20,50,150)
z <- runif(20,100,200)

df <- data.frame(date, index, x, y, z)
```

I would like to calculate the rolling mean for x, y and z, by a and then by b.

I tried the following, but I am getting an error.

```
test <- tapply(df, df$index, FUN = rollmean(df, 5, fill=NA))
```

The error:

```
Error in xu[k:n] - xu[c(1, seq_len(n - k))] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

It seems like there is an issue with the fact that index is a character, but I need it in order to calculate the means...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to do the trick using the library `dplyr` and `zoo`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df %>% 
  group_by(index) %>% 
  mutate(x_mean = rollmean(x, 5, fill = NA),
         y_mean = rollmean(y, 5, fill = NA),
         z_mean = rollmean(z, 5, fill = NA))
```

You could probably tidy this up more using `mutate_each` or some other form of `mutate`.

You can also change the arguments within `rollmean` to fit your needs, such as `align = "right"` or `na.pad = TRUE`

Answer (score 3):

**1) ave** Try `ave` rather than `tapply` and make sure it is applied only over the columns of interest, i.e. columns 3, 4, 5.

```
roll <- function(x) rollmean(x, 5, fill = NA)
cbind(df[1:2], lapply(df[3:5], function(x) ave(x, df$index, FUN = roll)))
```

giving:

```
         date index        x         y        z
1  2015-02-01     a       NA        NA       NA
2  2015-02-02     a       NA        NA       NA
3  2015-02-03     a 66.50522 127.45650 129.8472
4  2015-02-04     a 61.71320 123.83633 129.7673
5  2015-02-05     a 56.56125 120.86158 126.1371
6  2015-02-06     a 66.13340 119.93428 127.1819
7  2015-02-07     a 59.56807 105.83208 125.1244
8  2015-02-08     a 49.98779  95.66024 139.2321
9  2015-02-09     a       NA        NA       NA
10 2015-02-10     a       NA        NA       NA
11 2015-02-01     b       NA        NA       NA
12 2015-02-02     b       NA        NA       NA
13 2015-02-03     b 55.71327 117.52219 139.3961
14 2015-02-04     b 54.58450 107.81763 142.6101
15 2015-02-05     b 50.48102 104.94084 136.3167
16 2015-02-06     b 37.89790  95.45489 135.4044
17 2015-02-07     b 33.05259  85.90916 150.8673
18 2015-02-08     b 49.91385  90.04940 147.1376
19 2015-02-09     b       NA        NA       NA
20 2015-02-10     b       NA        NA       NA
```

**2) by** Another way is to use `by`.  `roll2` handles one group, `by` applies it to each group producing a `by` list and `do.call("rbind", ...)` puts it back together.

```
roll2 <- function(x) cbind(x[1:2], rollmean(x[3:5], 5, fill = NA))
do.call("rbind", by(df, df$index, roll2))
```

giving:

```
           date index        x         y        z
a.1  2015-02-01     a       NA        NA       NA
a.2  2015-02-02     a       NA        NA       NA
a.3  2015-02-03     a 66.50522 127.45650 129.8472
a.4  2015-02-04     a 61.71320 123.83633 129.7673
a.5  2015-02-05     a 56.56125 120.86158 126.1371
a.6  2015-02-06     a 66.13340 119.93428 127.1819
a.7  2015-02-07     a 59.56807 105.83208 125.1244
a.8  2015-02-08     a 49.98779  95.66024 139.2321
a.9  2015-02-09     a       NA        NA       NA
a.10 2015-02-10     a       NA        NA       NA
b.11 2015-02-01     b       NA        NA       NA
b.12 2015-02-02     b       NA        NA       NA
b.13 2015-02-03     b 55.71327 117.52219 139.3961
b.14 2015-02-04     b 54.58450 107.81763 142.6101
b.15 2015-02-05     b 50.48102 104.94084 136.3167
b.16 2015-02-06     b 37.89790  95.45489 135.4044
b.17 2015-02-07     b 33.05259  85.90916 150.8673
b.18 2015-02-08     b 49.91385  90.04940 147.1376
b.19 2015-02-09     b       NA        NA       NA
b.20 2015-02-10     b       NA        NA       NA
```

**3) wide form** Another approach is to convert `df` from long form to wide form in which case a plain `rollmean` will do it.

```
rollmean(read.zoo(df, split = 2), 5, fill = NA)
```

giving:

```
                x.a       y.a      z.a      x.b       y.b      z.b
2015-02-01       NA        NA       NA       NA        NA       NA
2015-02-02       NA        NA       NA       NA        NA       NA
2015-02-03 66.50522 127.45650 129.8472 55.71327 117.52219 139.3961
2015-02-04 61.71320 123.83633 129.7673 54.58450 107.81763 142.6101
2015-02-05 56.56125 120.86158 126.1371 50.48102 104.94084 136.3167
2015-02-06 66.13340 119.93428 127.1819 37.89790  95.45489 135.4044
2015-02-07 59.56807 105.83208 125.1244 33.05259  85.90916 150.8673
2015-02-08 49.98779  95.66024 139.2321 49.91385  90.04940 147.1376
2015-02-09       NA        NA       NA       NA        NA       NA
2015-02-10       NA        NA       NA       NA        NA       NA
```

This works because the dates are the same for both groups.  If the dates were different then it could introduce NAs and `rollmean` cannot handle those.  In that case use

```
rollapply(read.zoo(df, split = 2), 5, mean, fill = NA)
```

**Note:** Since the input uses random numbers in its definition to make it reproducible we must issue `set.seed` first. We used  this:

```
set.seed(123)
date <- as.Date(c("2015-02-01", "2015-02-02", "2015-02-03", "2015-02-04", 
          "2015-02-05", "2015-02-06", "2015-02-07", "2015-02-08",  
          "2015-02-09", "2015-02-10", "2015-02-01", "2015-02-02", 
          "2015-02-03", "2015-02-04", "2015-02-05", "2015-02-06", 
          "2015-02-07", "2015-02-08", "2015-02-09", "2015-02-10"))
index <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a",
           "b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b")
x <- runif(20,1,100)
y <- runif(20,50,150)
z <- runif(20,100,200)
```